# Open 3D issues creating a 3D mesh

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, mesh, open3d

I am trying to create a 3D mesh in Open3D given a set of 3D points. My code is the following:

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
hull, _ = pcd.compute_convex_hull()
hull_ls = o3d.geometry.LineSet.create_from_triangle_mesh(hull)
hull_ls.paint_uniform_color((1, 0, 0))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, hull_ls])
```

The visualization I obtain is the following:

[image]

The main issue is that there are 2 points that are not connected correctly. See highlighted area.

What I am trying to obtain instead is something like this:

[image]

The second image was drawn using Open3D LineSet, since I have the points and order in which they need to be connected. The issue with the second visualization is that I am not able to export is a mesh file, since it is just a set of line.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The expected mesh is not a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). Therefore, `compute_convex_hull` will not produce the expected result anyways.

You should be able to export a `LineSet` using [write_line_set](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.write_line_set.html) and read using [read_line_set](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_line_set.html).